# How can i add input field class(bootstrap class) "form-control" to {{form.as_p}}?

Tags: django, bootstrap-4

How can i add input field class(bootstrap class) "form-control" to {{form.as_p}} ??

```
            <form class="form-inline" action="" method="post">

                {% csrf_token %}

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-sm-4">

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6 ">

                        {{form.as_p}} <br>

                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="OK" />

                        <a href="/login/home">

                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="HOME" />

                        </a>

                    </div>

                </div>

    </form>
```

forms.py

```
class NameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Register
        fields = "__all__"
```

where i want to add the **init** method in form?

Comment: What is inside {{form.as_p}}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it by overriding the `__init__` method in your `Form`

```
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NameForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields.values():
            field.widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}

    class Meta:
        model = Register
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: where i want to add the __init__() to forms.py file

Comment: error showing --->   for field in self.fields.values()    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Anjitha sorry, I missed the symbol `:`. updated the answer. plz check.

Comment: Isn't it `for field in self.fields:`  ?

Comment: @art06 no, if you do that you will get a "string" instead field object.